# Need simultaneous working of Axios post for data and file from React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I can either have my axios post send some data ( example below ) or FormData.  How would I set the call up so that I can send it all at once.  The problem is that if I send both simultaneously, it doesn't send anything at all.  My current call is :

```
  async handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
const { name, email, message } = this.state;
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file',this.state.file)
const config = {
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
}

const form = await axios.post("/api/formPDF", {
  name, ******
  email, *****
  message ****
}).post("/api/formPDF", formData, config);
}
```

The section I have indicated with * is where I believe my problem to be.  The way I have it send now, I will have access to name/email/message on req.body.  If I remove the object of the three, and replace it with formData it will correctly email the file but everything is clearly undefined.  If I edit it as so :

```
const form = await axios.post("/api/formPDF", {
  name,
  email,
  message,
  formData
```

It makes it so both my req.body and the way I parse my file is an empty object.  My relevant server code is :

```
app.post("/api/formPDF", (req, res) => {
var fileLoc, fileExt, fileName, fileEmail, fileMessage;

var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {

console.log("Files: ", files);
fileLoc = files.file.path;
fileExt = files.file.name.split('.').pop();

});

nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {

const htmlEmail = `
  <h3>Contact Details</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
    <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
  </ul>
  <h3>Message</h3>
  <p>${req.body.message}</p>
`

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  name: *removed*,
  host: *removed*,
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    user: *removed*,
    pass: *removed*
  }
})

let mailOptions = {
  from: *removed*,
  to: *removed*,
  replyTo: req.body.email,
  subject: "New Message",
  text: req.body.message,
  html: htmlEmail,
  attachments: [
    {
      filename: `${req.body.name}Resume.${fileExt}`,
      path: fileLoc
    }
 ]
};

fileLoc = "";

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }
})
})
});
```

Am I missing something that is causing the objects to be empty?  I know its not possible to read the formData client side, but I should be able to see it on my server.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using Promise.all([post(""),post("")]) to post data at once?